# Outlook doesn't get push emails from hosted exchange server

Tags: exchange, hosting

Somehow my outlook stopped getting push emails from the my provider of the hosted exchange server.
It happens on multiple computers and I can get the emails or synchronize the folders only by disconnecting from the server and connecting again.
From the other hand - I still get the pushed emails quickly and directly to my Iphone.
Tried to update outlook to 2010 but it doesn't help.

Is it a problem with the hosted exchange provider ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot that could be the issue from exchange connectors to just a small client issue.

Are you currently running in cached exchange mode?  If so try turning that off and see if it helps.  Also double check to make sure your firewall rules are not being blocked.  It could be a simple routing issue as well but again this is where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check with your admin.  They have logs that show how often your client contacts their servers.  If it looks a ok from that side, I'd try outlook on a different computer and make sure it isn't your isp.